# Lighttpd not showing error reporting

Tags: php, lighttpd

I recently installed lighttpd and php5 through this http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/light-webserver guide. I enabled error reporting in php.ini but `phpinfo()` keeps telling that error reporting is disabled. When I use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in my php file, it also doesn't seem to work.

I'm using the php.ini that `phpinfo()` refers to.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to your php code.